# Is there a way to create a STRAIGHT_JOIN using Laravel's ORM?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have one query where I need to use a STRAIGHT_JOIN for performance reasons. The query is built like this:

```
$query->join('tbl2 as b', function ($join) {
            $join->on('a.b_id', '=', 'b.id')
                ->where('b.x_id', $x);
        })
```

Is there any way to force the query to use STRAIGHT_JOIN? It looks like this is impossible because there's no space (like you would have with INNERT JOIN, LEFT JOIN, etc).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It appears that `SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN <cols> ...` solves the problem. This can be done relatively easily by manipulating the list of columns to select and automatically applies to all joins in the query.

Comment: Have you tried this?  Laravel quotes column names, and ``SELECT `STRAIGHT_JOIN` <cols> ...`` won't work...

Comment: You need to use DB::raw() to avoid the quoting. It works.

Comment: Using DB::raw() you can use STRAIGHT_JOIN in the FROM clause, which is what my answer says??

Comment: I don't know why you've been downvoted. This does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible.

When compiling the SQL, Laravel hardcodes whitespace between the join type and the `JOIN` keyword—so, like you say, it cannot be persuaded to use `STRAIGHT_JOIN`.   See [`Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar::compileJoins()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php#L180):

> ```
>             $sql[] = "$type join $table on $clauses";
> ```

You will have to [run a raw query](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database#running-queries).

Comment: I upvoted this before I found out that STRAIGHT_JOIN can indeed be added to the list of columns selected instead of being added to the list of tables, which is trivial to do in a Laravel query. Good to know how the joins are built though.

Comment: @user83358: You can only do that by running a raw query, which is what my answer says.

Comment: I did it without running a raw query

Comment: @user83358: Could you explain how?  [Your previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37449266/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-straight-join-using-laravels-orm/37557841#comment62981329_37557841) said "*You need to use DB::raw() to avoid the quoting. It works.*"

Comment: You have to manipulate the columns selected to get this result. Using DB::raw() is necessary to avoid the MySQL keyword being quoted. The rest of the query is build using the standard Laravel methods.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the addSelect method for STRAIGHT_JOIN. But we also need to be careful in order to avoid the unnecessary back-ticks (`) and commas (,).

SQL query:

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN 
    employee.salary as `e.salary`,
    ...
    ...
FROM employee 
LEFT JOIN department 
    ON employee.dept_id = department.id 
LEFT JOIN projects 
    ON employee.project_id = project.id
LEFT JOIN ... 
    ON ...
WHERE
    employee.doj BETWEEN (start_date, end_date) 
    AND ....
    OR ....
ORDER BY employee.dob ASC;
```

Code:

```
protected function addStraightJoinUsingSelectFields()
{
    $selectFields = $this->getSelectFields(); // get select fields array

    $firstFieldArray = explode(' AS ', $selectFields[0]); // get the 0th element and split on ' AS '.
    // "employee.salary AS e.salary" => array([0] => "employee.salary", [1] => "e.salary")

    $firstFieldArray[1] = '`' . trim($firstFieldArray[1], '`') . '`'; // "`e.salary`"

    $firstFieldString = implode($firstFieldArray, ' AS '); // "employee.salary AS `e.salary`"

    $straightJoinColumn = 'straight_join ' . $firstFieldString; // "straight_join employee.salary AS `e.salary`"

    $selectFields[0] = \DB::raw($straightJoinColumn);

    foreach ($selectFields as $fieldToSelect)
    {
        $this->query->addSelect($fieldToSelect);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Model::query()
->from(DB::raw("table1 straight_join table2 on table1.id = table12.task_id"))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel form function

```
Model::query()
->from(DB::raw("table1 straight_join table2 on table1.id = table12.task_id"))
.......
```